# prevent displaying HTML object attached programatically until the object startup JS has completed

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have a JavaScript dashboard framework that loads HTML widgets as objects (document.createElement) which once loaded execute startup JavaScript logic in the HTML widget. Previous version of this dashboard was only used in IE 10/11 and I could hide the object using the CSS display: hidden property until the object was fully loaded and completed its startup code which typically adjusted the way the widget looked on the screen (eg. change background color based on the setting saved for the widget). Once complete I could change the CSS display setting to inline to show the widget.

Now I'm trying to get this to work in Chrome and the new MS Edge browser, and it seems I was previously relying on an IE quirk as both Edge and Chrome won't allow manipulation of the object if its CSS display properties is 'none' when it is first loaded. If the object is visible when loaded this means the end user sees each widget load in a transitory state and 'morph' to its final state while it's startup JavaScript is run, which isn't pretty.

What I'd like to do is have the object hidden until it's startup is complete. I have tried a combination of relevant CSS properties like setting height to 0, display: none and visibility: hidden, as well as adjusting z-index so the object sits behind a splash screen (appendChild seems to override z-index settings).

I could have the object manage its display by itself but I'd much rather the dashboard framework handle it instead.

Any ideas how I can hide a dynamically loaded HTML object until I'm ready to show it (once all objects are loaded)? I can use jQuery in the dashboard but not in the object itself (too heavy), although if there is a jQuery answer it can be done in native JavaScript also (my preference). And note the solution only supports modern HTML5 browsers.

(If the above isn't clear I'll setup a fiddle). Thanks!

Comment: _"If the above isn't clear I'll setup a fiddle"_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: It's actually allowed to modify an element style when it's not visible... your problem is somewhere else. You can even manipulate the style (e.g. the background color) when the element is not yet inserted in the DOM...

Comment: @6502 if it's hidden, JS cannot get its size for instance - and if that would be required to manage widget's content, it's not practical for the widget to remain hidden

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: you can modify the style but you cannot ask about properties that depends on the visibility and on CSS rules, of course. OP was talking about the background color however, and you can set that before showing it (or even before adding the element to the DOM).

Comment: OK thanks - a couple of ideas here for me to try (I have already tried negative top/left but will try again). Give me some time to try some of these and post back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be very well managed using absolute positioning.

**CSS:**

```
.hiddenWidget {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10000px;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

You'd assign this class to the new widget and remove it once it's updated via JS.

Comment: This did work out the best way to approach the problem, I had tried it previously but hadn't set the test up correctly, have it working now. Thanks for the sanity check.